# Getting 403 Error when Accessing Google Cloud Storage Bucket via S3 Generic

Tags: cloud-storage

I am trying to save backups from our Website Network to a Google Cloud Storare Nearline Bucket via the Updraft plus Wordpress Plugin. The PlugIn claims to have succsessfully connected to my bucket.

"Successfully connected. We were able to use the bucket and create files in it. The connection was encrypted."

However, when I try to upload the backup, I get a 403 forbidden Error. Is there something I need to do in the Google Admin Console, some rights I need to grant? I can't find anything useful :/

This is the Error:

```
0039.941 (0) Saving backup history. Total backup size: 366.7 MB
0039.955 (0) Requesting upload of the files that have not yet been successfully uploaded (5)
0039.960 (0) Cloud backup selection (1/1): s3generic with instance (1/1) (last)
0039.961 (0) Beginning dispatch of backup to remote (s3generic) (instance identifier s-f1ecbdca7de6aada6eb49815ca9374ca)
0040.371 (0) S3-Compatible (Generic): Set endpoint: storage.googleapis.com
0040.373 (0) S3-Compatible (Generic): upload (n/a): backup_2019-04-01-1218_Pando_Media_b5f0f2c0e14e-plugins.zip (chunks: 4) -> s3generic://pando-media-backups/backup_2019-04-01-1218_Pando_Media_b5f0f2c0e14e-plugins.zip
0040.437 (0) S3-Compatible (Generic): exception (UpdraftPlus_S3Exception) whilst trying initiateMultipartUpload: **UpdraftPlus_S3::initiateMultipartUpload(): [403] Unexpected HTTP status (line: 586, file: /var/www/ud07_1/html/pando/wp-content/plugins/updraftplus/includes/S3.php)**
0040.439 (0) S3-Compatible (Generic): upload: failed: could not get uploadId for multipart upload (backup_2019-04-01-1218_Pando_Media_b5f0f2c0e14e-plugins.zip)
0040.440 (0) An error condition has occurred for the first time during this job
```

Thank you!

Valentin

Comment: looks like s3 blocked by your provider or by AWS.

Comment: @JamesM The question is why. I assume there is something I need to change with the Bucket / Project Settings. We are NOT talking about AWS btw, we are talking about Google Cloud Storage via S3 generic access.